# How to update stripe default set Customer Default Source in android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am currently using stripe 'com.stripe:stripe-android:15.0.1'and calling presentPaymentMethodSelection to present payment activity flow. I am using subscription service hence I need only to show-card, set a default card, and add a new card. I think for android stripe still don't have onClick stripe default source update like ios. So I am using setCustomerDefaultSource to solve the purpose.

issues
1: getting default-source = null.

2: not able to update card = receive "No such source: 'pm_*********************'"

error received on card click:

```
errorCode = 400
errorMessage = "No such source: 'pm_*********************'"
stripeError = {Stripe****} 
 charge = ""
 code = "resource_missing"
 declineCode = ""
 message = "No such source: 'pm_*********************'"
 param = "source"
 type = "invalid_request_error"
 shadow$_klass_ = {Cla***} "class com.stripe.android.StripeError"
 shadow$_monitor_ = 0
```

here is a card info

```
0 = {PaymentMethod0} 
 billingDetails = {PaymentMethod$Billin} 
 card = {PaymentMethod$Car} 
 cardPresent = null
 created = {Long@10} 
 customerId = "cus_**************er"
 id = "pm_*********************"
 ideal = null
 liveMode = false
 metadata = {HashMap@###}  size = 0
 type = "card"
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@$$$} "class com.stripe.android.model.PaymentMethod"
 shadow$_monitor_ = 0
```

and parameters of below function
paymentId:"pm_*********************"

```
     mCustomerSessionN.setCustomerDefaultSource(paymentId, Source.SourceType.CARD, new CustomerSession.CustomerRetrievalListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomerRetrieved(@NonNull Customer customer) {
                Log.d("", "onCustomerRetrieved: " + customer);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Card is added ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int errorCode, @NonNull String errorMessage, @Nullable StripeError stripeError) {
                Log.d("", "onCustomerRetrieved: " + errorMessage);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's mobile SDK components such as PaymentSession/CustomerSession which you are using, now default to creating PaymentMethod objects (e.g. Stripe Android after v9.1.0 moved to PaymentMethod objects).

PaymentMethod objects are somewhat different from the legacy Token/Source/Card objects in that they can still be attached to a Customer but they don't automatically have a "default" concept.

Right now, you're setting a `source` field on a Customer to a PaymentMethod object, which isn't supported (`source` is a legacy field so it supports a Token or Source object only).

What you instead want is to use the `attachPaymentMethod()` function on CustomerSession [0], to attach the PaymentMethod to the Customer.

Then server-side, when you create the Subscription, you would also pass `default_payment_method: pm_123` to specify which of the attached PaymentMethod you want to create a Subscription on [1].

[0] https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/stripe/com.stripe.android/-customer-session/attach-payment-method.html

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-default_payment_method

Comment: Thanks. So in CustomerSession.attachPaymentMethod returns me paymentMethord when default_payment_method(pm_***) passed to i. so now you want me generate token and to go for api call to server and server make me that particular card default?

Comment: Correct, you can attach the PaymentMethod to the Customer via CustomerSession/PaymentSession. But it does not get identified as "the default PaymentMethod to use for Invoices and Subscription". That you will have to do via a server-side call, to specify the Customer's `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`

Comment: Thanks @hmunoz, I contacted stripe support. and they suggested the same thing.